# High amount of polynomials in many variables

Tags: z3

I have something between 20 and 200 polynomials in about 100 or 200 variables. All have a similar form to this one

x(6)(1)(1)*y(1)(1)^2+x(6)(2)(1)*y(1)(1)*y(2)(1)+x(6)(2)(2)*y(2)(1)^2+x(6)(3)(1)*y(1)(1)*y(3)(1)+x(6)(3)(2)*y(2)(1)*y(3)(1)+x(6)(3)(3)*y(3)(1)^2+x(6)(4)(1)*y(1)(1)*y(4)(1)+x(6)(4)(2)*y(2)(1)*y(4)(1)+x(6)(4)(3)*y(3)(1)*y(4)(1)+x(6)(4)(4)*y(4)(1)^2+x(6)(5)(1)*y(1)(1)*y(5)(1)+x(6)(5)(2)*y(2)(1)*y(5)(1)+x(6)(5)(3)*y(3)(1)*y(5)(1)+x(6)(5)(4)*y(4)(1)*y(5)(1)+x(6)(5)(5)*y(5)(1)^2

This is from singular. The brackets are just indices for the the variables. So this a degree 3 polynomial in 20 variables or something. And all coefficients are +-1.

Can Z3 solve the following problem in a reasonable time or do I not even have to try Z3 here?
Is there a real x such that 50 such polynomials are zero and 50 are non-zero in x.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to say without trying. Z3 has a decision procedure for nonlinear-real arithmetic, so in theory; yes, it can answer these questions. But how "quick," is anybody's guess. The community would appreciate if you actually do try and report what you find out!

Answer (score 0):

Now I did just try it. So the problem where only 80 polynomials have to vanish and none have to be nonzero is working really well. It takes about half an hour or so. This is most likely due to the fact that there are "simple" answers in that case, meaning lots of zeros.

But as soon as I add one polynomial and require it to be nonzero it becomes much worse. After 1 day there is still no result. But since I do not know if there even is a positive answer, Z3 probably has to try everything, so this was to be expected I think.

One more question: Assuming there is no answer to the problem, meaning Z3 is eventually outputting "non-sat". Is there any way Z3 can output any kind of progress during its search, so I am able to at least have some kind of worst case time?